# Capture returned Access and Refresh token in Web Api

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'am using OAuth authentication with Web Api. And for audit purpose I need to capture the returned json that contain the access_token and the refresh_token.
I've tried to use a DelegationHandler but no success, seems that the Authentication process in out of the reach of the handler.

Is there any way to capture the json returned to the client ?

Comment: How are you using the OAuth authentication? Are you using the built in Katana classes where you configure your OWIN settings?

Answer (score 0):

I have a console app that is used for testing my web API. This is how I get the JSON data:

```
response = await client.PostAsync("api/token", formContent);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
    var token = jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
    var refreshToken = jObject.GetValue("refresh_token").ToString();
}
```